# Adding images just for Retina

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to target users that only have retina displays/have a particular version of iOS? If not, do I need to include non-retina images in my project? I know that for the application icon it needs a non-retina version, but for all of my custom graphics, such as UIBarButton icons, etc. do they all need to have both a retain (test@2x.png) and a regular (test.png) version?

Also, how should I go about scaling? Currently I'm creating say a larger image, like 100x100px and then scaling it down with the following code:

```
 // grab the original image
    UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
    // scaling set to 2.0 makes the image 1/2 the size.
    UIImage *scaledImage =
    [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[originalImage CGImage]
                        scale:(originalImage.scale * 2.0)
                  orientation:(originalImage.imageOrientation)];
```

Does this maintain a higher resolution than if I re-sized it to 50x50 pixels in photoshop and then added the file into my project as is?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881132/stop-using-retina-only-images?rq=1) and see if it helps at all.

Comment: @RicPerrott that does help a lot. My only follow up question would be, can I prevent users below a particular ios target from downloading my application? Thanks for your help!

Comment: In Build Settings, set "iOS Deployment Target" to the highest version of iOS you'd like to support. Devices with lower versions of iOS will not be able to download your app.

Comment: @SanjayChaudhry exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot specify users device.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better add two versions for all images into your app.

Because you could not know whether the device is retina or not.